# Протокол HTTP и HTTPS

Tags: .htaccess, http, ssl, https

Здравствуйтe. Есть сайт с картинкой по адресу `https://example.com/123.png`
Почему, если в коде принудительно поставить адрес картинки по протоколу HTTP `<img src="HTTP://example.com/123.png">` эта картинка при отображении в браузере загрузится по протоколу HTTPS, хотя редиректов нет?

Comment: Ставлю на наличие HSTS в ответе сервера

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это поведение разнится от браузера к браузеру.
Google давно борется за продвижение HTTPS в интернете, для безопасности пользователей. Соответственно в браузере Google Chrome вводятся ограничения на работу с сайтами неиспользующими защищенный протокол. Что касается принудительного редиректа:

> Январь 2020 — в Chrome 80 аудио- и видеоконтент будет автоматически
> загружаться с HTTPS. Если загрузка по HTTPS не будет успешной, Chrome
> заблокирует такие ресурсы. При необходимости пользователи смогут
> вручную разблокировать их. В Chrome 80 изображения, загружаемые на
> HTTPS-сайтах c HTTP, блокироваться не будут, но появится сообщение,
> что соединение небезопасное.
>
> Февраль 2020 — в Chrome 81 изображения будут автоматически загружаться с HTTPS. Если они окажутся недоступными, браузер заблокирует их.

В Firefox и Chromium тоже есть что-то подобное.